# Errors with math in MySQLi

Tags: php, math, mysqli

When i'm using MySQLi i get some math errors when i did this:

```
    <?php
include "mysqliconnect.php"; //Some connect details
    $gQuery = $db->query("SELECT Waarde FROM Codes WHERE Code='".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['codej'])."'");

    while($row1 = $gQuery->fetch_assoc()){

        $gQuery2 = $db->query("SELECT balance FROM Users WHERE gnaam='Sombie'");

        while($row2 = $gQuery2->fetch_assoc()) {

            $money3 = $row1+$row2;
    ?>
```

The variable $money3 is unusable. 
If i do echo $money3; then it will display nothing. Can anybody tell me whats wrong about it?


Thanks!

Comment: Is that your full and actually code, or is there more? If that's your full code, you've a few missing braces.

Comment: Tried debugging it? `var_dump()` will help you.

Comment: That isn't my full code. @Gerald Schneider I'll get this: array(2) { ["Worth"]=> string(3) "363" ["balance"]=> string(2) "99" }  We can see: the variables don't added.

Comment: Can you please tell the error you are getting

Comment: @Utkarsh Thats the weird thing: i don't get errors

Comment: Is error reporting on? Are you using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`?

Comment: FYI, escaping `$_POST` content does not prevent injection, your database will be p0wnd - use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Which statement?

Comment: Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is absolute wrong. Use the code below

```
<?php
include "mysqliconnect.php"; //Some connect details
    $gQuery = $db->query("SELECT Waarde FROM Codes WHERE Code='".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['codej'])."'");

    while($row1 = $gQuery->fetch_assoc()){

        $gQuery2 = $db->query("SELECT balance FROM Users WHERE gnaam='Sombie'");

        while($row2 = $gQuery2->fetch_assoc()) {

            $money3 = $row1['Waarde']+$row2['balance'];
    ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I thought the same thing. Another method OP could use is MySQL's [`SUM`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/) aggregate function; it's an option.

Comment: No problem You are welcome. Please choose this answer as correct answer